# how to use mavlink?

Tags: ros, mavlink

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi there,

i have ardupilot hexacopter equipped with pandaboard running ros.
so i installed this mavlink-ros-pkg to control my copter via ros from here http://qgroundcontrol.org/dev/mavlink_ros_robot_operation_system_integration_tutorial. mavlink compiled fine and by running rosrun mavlink_ros mavlink_ros_serial -p /dev/ttyACM0 it publishes some data to rostopic. but now i am not sure how to use this node to control my copter?

i did find this message documentation here: https://pixhawk.ethz.ch/mavlink/ but i don`t know how to use them with ros so that my ardu gets this messages. could anyone explain, please?

i would be very happy if i could send a command like "start" through the terminal and the hexacopter starts and holds position at 3m for example.
or is there any teleop-stack ready? this would be very great.

thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60314/how-to-use-mavlink?/) by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Giona Grancheli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4854/giona-grancheli/) on 2013-05-10**:
I have the same problem :(

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-05-18**:
Hi, did you find any document or wiki at last? I can find one nowhere(

**Comment by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on 2014-05-19**:
hi there, for the start i recommend to work with "roscopter". this one woks, but there is still a lot of work. good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI

you could try this python generator:

https://github.com/posilva/mav2rosgenerator

Best

Pedro

---

Originally posted by [pmosilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/19772/pmosilva/) with karma: 56 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0